# How to retrieve only one string from a cURL response

Tags: php, json, curl, github-api

I am using the following code to get information about a repo using the Github API.

I am using cURL, but I'm not sure how to just get the name of the repository. So, how can I get just one string from the response and `echo` that without echoing the complete response? I tried doing `$data['name']` but that didn't work.

code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Content-type: application/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/repos/ruby/ruby');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

Comment: What do you get back from the cURL call? Post it in your question.

Comment: it's kind of big, but the same as https://api.github.com/repos/ruby/ruby

Comment: _“I tried doing $data['name'] but that didn't work”_ – of course it didn’t, because `$data` is just a string of text, and not an array or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request returns JSON, so just use `json_decode`.

```
$jsonStr = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
var_dump($json['name']);
var_dump($json['full_name']);
```

It should be trivial from here to get the elements you're interested in.